# IE reverses expected SVG's percentage background-position behaviour

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm positioning a background SVG with CSS in a responsive element with the following code:

```js
var theSVG = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"><g><path fill="#888888" d="M218.7,272.5l-38.6-80.6c-0.4-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8-0.7l-23.4,8.8h-7.8l-23.4-8.8c-1.1-0.4-2.4-0.1-2.8,1 l-38.6,80.4c-0.4,1.1,0.2,2.3,1.3,2.7l2.4,0.8c1.1,0.4,2.4-0.2,2.8-1.3l49.5-56.9l8.5,77.9c0,1.2,1,2.3,2.2,2.3h3.2 c1.2,0,2.2-1.1,2.2-2.3l8.6-79l50.2,58c0.4,1.1,1.6,1.7,2.8,1.3l2.4-0.8C218.5,274.8,219.1,273.6,218.7,272.5z"/><path fill="#555555" d="M184.2,2h-66.5C108.1,2,100,9.7,100,19.4v103c0,8,5.5,14.8,12.8,16.9c-1.3,1.2-2.2,2.8-2.2,4.7l7.8,52 c0,3.5,2.9,6.9,6.3,6.9h50.9c3.5,0,6.3-3.4,6.3-6.9l9.3-51.7c0-1.9-0.3-3.7-1.6-4.9c7.4-2.1,13.3-9.1,13.3-17.1v-103 C203,9.7,194,2,184.2,2z M192,112.9c0,3.4-2.7,6.1-6.1,6.1h-67.7c-3.4,0-6.1-2.7-6.1-6.1V19.1c0-3.4,2.7-6.1,6.1-6.1h67.7 c3.4,0,6.1,2.7,6.1,6.1V112.9z"/><path fill="#888888" d="M205.6,184.5H96.5c-1.3,0-2.3-1.1-2.3-2.3v-9c0-1.3,1.1-2.3,2.3-2.3h109.1c1.3,0,2.3,1.1,2.3,2.3v9 C207.9,183.5,206.8,184.5,205.6,184.5z"/><g><path fill="#AAAAAA" d="M119.9,151h-28c-2.9,0-5.2-2.3-5.2-5.2V31.4c0-2.9,2.3-5.2,5.2-5.2h28c2.9,0,5.2,2.3,5.2,5.2v114.5 C125.1,148.7,122.8,151,119.9,151z"/><path fill="#AAAAAA" d="M210.2,151h-28c-2.9,0-5.2-2.3-5.2-5.2V31.4c0-2.9,2.3-5.2,5.2-5.2h28c2.9,0,5.2,2.3,5.2,5.2v114.5 C215.3,148.7,213,151,210.2,151z"/><path fill="#AAAAAA" d="M151,91c-13.1,0-23.8-10.7-23.8-23.8s10.7-23.8,23.8-23.8s23.8,10.7,23.8,23.8S164.1,91,151,91z M151,52.1 c-8.3,0-15.1,6.8-15.1,15.1s6.8,15.1,15.1,15.1c8.3,0,15.1-6.8,15.1-15.1S159.4,52.1,151,52.1z"/></g></g></svg>';
var theSVG64 = window.btoa(theSVG);
document.getElementById('svgholder').style.backgroundImage = "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+theSVG64+"')";
```

```css
.svgholder {
  background-color: #444;
  /* background-image: url("path-to-my-svg.svg"); */
  /* On the site the svg is specified above, but for this example I'm setting the data with JS so the contents can be seen un-base64 encoded */
  background-size: auto 130%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 10% top 20%;
  width: 80%;
  min-width:640px;
  min-height:300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgholder" id="svgholder">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

If this is viewed in any modern browser other than IE, the `background-position: left 10% top 20%` property causes the SVG to shift *right* by 10%, and up by 20%. In IE(10/11) it shifts *left* by 10% and up by 20%.

If a negative percentage is set, i.e. `background-position: left -10% top 20%` the reverse happens. Note that the `top 20%` renders the same in all cases.

You'll see I'm using four-value syntax here, but the same happens if it's two-value. i.e. `background-position: 10% 20%;`

I wonder if this an IE bug, and if there is a workaround that would make IE behave like the others.

Bonus oddity: If `preserveAspectRatio="none"` is set in the SVG, the effect is reversed. IE 'adds' the percentage set, and others subtract it from the position.

Comment: background-position takes 2 values at the most for X,Y axis : does  background-position: left 30%; works better ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEvbrJ

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks, I should have added 'auto' to the end for proper four value syntax (and should have said it was CSS3). But alas the same problem is demonstrated with `background-position: 30% 10%`. Cheers!